# applying jquery on escape key event while playing you tube video in iframe

Tags: jquery, iframe, youtube, embed, keypress

I am embedding a you tube video in a div and ahow it on click of a button. Now I want to hide the div on escape keypress event.

***Html***

```
<div 
class="divpop" 
id='<iframe width="640" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/5uGo0L4ribY" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>'><img class="project-img project-img-visible" src="images/videos/img1.jpg" alt=""'>
</div>
```

***Jquery***

```
$(".divpop").click(function(){
       $("#popup_video").html((this).id);
      });
$(#popup_video).keypress(function(e){
     if (e.which==0){
       $("#popup_video").empty();
     } });
```

Comment: This isn't what ID attributes are for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an extremely unorthodox means of doing what you are trying to achieve.

I'd like to recommend that you put the dynamic variables of the youtube video in *expando* properties.

***Html***

```
<div class="divpop" youtube_width="640" youtube_height="480" youtube_vid="5uGo0L4ribY">
    <img class="project-img project-img-visible" src="images/videos/img1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

As for hiding the video, you need to target the document, and keycode '27' for Escape

***Jquery***

```
$(".divpop").click(function(){
    // Create new iframe entity:
    var $yt_embed = $('<iframe/>'); //dollar before variable indicates jquery object
    // Instantiate and assign attributes
    var yt_url = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+$(this).attr('youtube_vid');
    $yt_embed.attr( 'src', yt_url )
             .attr( 'width', $(this).attr('youtube_width') )
             .attr( 'height', $(this).attr('youtube_height') );
    $("#popup_video").html($yt_embed);
});


$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 27) { $('#popup_video').empty(); }   // esc
});
```

Here's the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/yAvBh/2/

Comment: Zmart completely agree with your approach. But the solution is still not working.
escape key works only when video is not played , once iframe is clicked ie. once video is played, it captures all controls and escape key doesn't work

Comment: Perhaps add something that will bring the focus back to the document, Trishul?

Comment: Same problem here. I am trying to use Mousetrap to bind to keyevents, and no success so far, even when using my own event listeners.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but I came across the same issue.

Here is my solution:

As Zmart stated your approach for filling the video dynamically is a bit odd, I would do the following:

```
<div class="divpop" yt_width="640" yt_height="480" yt_vid="5uGo0L4ribY">
    <img class="project-img project-img-visible" src="images/videos/img1.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Bind this when your popup loads and unbind when it closes. Or leave it there all the time if you have no other items on your page that require focus.

```
$(".divpop").click(function(){
    $(window).on("blur.videopopup", function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(window).focus();
        },500);
    });
    $(window).on("keyup.videopopup", function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 27) { $('#popup_video').empty(); $(window).off('.videopopup'); }   // esc
    });
    $("#popup_video").html('<iframe width="'+$(this).attr('yt_width')+'" height="'+$(this).attr('yt_width')+" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/'+$(this).attr('yt_vid')+'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
});
```